# Java Packages - Import vs Explicit Inclusion

Tags: java, import, package

I thought I reasonably understood the use of packages but am experiencing an ostensibly trivial issue when attempting to use a method from an imported package.

I have three files in the following directory structure:

- Tester.java
- approach1\Approach.java
- approach2\Approach.java

Their code is as follows:

**Tester.java**

```
import approach1.Approach;

public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        approach1.Approach.sharedMethod("TEXT");

        sharedMethod("TEXT");
    }
}
```

**approach1\Approach.java**

```
package approach1; 

public class Approach {

    public static void sharedMethod(String approachText)
    {
        System.out.println("Approach Text: " + approachText);
    }
}
```

**approach2\Approach.java**

```
package approach2;

public class Approach {

    public static void sharedMethod(String approachText) { }

}
```

As you can likely guess, I'm trying to elicit different responses from the different approaches based on what package/class is imported. The problem I encounter is within **Tester.java**. The first, explicit line works fine whereas the second, imported line (sharedMethod("TEXT")) throws an error of *"The method sharedMethod(String) is undefined for the type Tester"*. I don't understand as I have imported one of the packages, so the method should be visible.

Any clarification would be appreicated as I'm a Java newb. Thanks!

Comment: A non-static import imports classes, not methods. You still need to specify the class when calling the method: `Approach.sharedMethod("TEXT");`

Answer (score 3):

You could import your static method `shareMethod` like this

```
import static approach1.Approach.sharedMethod;
```

Answer (score 0):

the standard kind of imports that you have used only import the classes - so everything within a class must be referenced using the class name. just use:

Approach.sharedMethod()

and  now the compiler will be able to know which method to use all depending on which Approach class you have imported at the top.

Just to clarify:

```
    import approach1.Approach;
    public class Tester {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Approach.sharedMethod("TEXT");
        }
    }
```

is different from

```
    import approach2.Approach;
    public class Tester {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Approach.sharedMethod("TEXT");
        }
    }
```

You should only specify the class name and leave it to the package import statement at the top to determine which package to find the class/methods from.

You only need to explicitly mention the package in the main program body if there is a conflict in names or if you have not imported anything.